# Questions tagged only as homework

Tags: discussion, tagging, homework

Lately I have found a massive amount of questions tagged *solely* as [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework), for instance

- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687358/rounding-up-to-significant-figures
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687400/the-magnitude-of-the-resultant
- [prove $v_i=(1^i,2^i,\dots,n^i)$, $i=0,\dots,n-1$ a basis for real $n$-space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687301/prove-a-list-to-be-a-basis)
- **[Query: open homework-only questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/75972/finding-posts-tagged-only-homework-which-are-not-closed)**
- **[Query: homework-only questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/59833/finding-posts-tagged-only-homework)**

*(thanks to @MartinSleziak for the queries)*

Despite the tag description explicitly stating *not* to use [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) as the only tag for a question. What do you think about addressing this issue with

- prohibiting the asker to post a question if it doesn't have a "proper" tag
- reminding (*warning*) the asker that his question is only tagged as [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) and that this is explicitly discouraged and ask him to find an appropriate tag (but allow posting if the asker doesn't find a suitable tag, within a certain time or by clicking a "continue anyways" button)

I find the latter rather appealing, since it may be that an asker doesn't know enough about mathematics or the tags used on this site to find those suitable for his question, but should be encouraged to at least try to find some. On the other hand this might lead to mis-tagged questions, so I'm not sure. Let me hear your opinion.

Comment: SEDE (data explorer): [Finding Posts tagged only homework, which are not closed](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/75972/finding-posts-tagged-only-homework-which-are-not-closed) and [Finding Posts tagged only homework](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/59833/finding-posts-tagged-only-homework)

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks, I included the queries in the OP.

Comment: Whenever I see a question with only the homework tag, I open it and, if I can come up with something sensible, add another tag. It appears that this is the best we can do.

Answer (score 1):

As a feature request (to add a software block or warning) this is hopeless: SE won't do it, as it's against their philosophy regarding [meta tags on main sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). But don't take my word for it, see these old feature requests:

- [Using [homework] tag by itself](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117/127096)
- [Feature-request: Not allowing [homework] as the only tag to a post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3069/127096)

I do support the idea of

> prohibiting the asker to post a question if it doesn't have a "proper" tag

but I'd like to see it done by means of deleting and blacklisting the [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag.

Comment: So basically, nuke the tag like Stack Overflow did?